# importing sass file returns empty object or global stylesheet is ignored

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

When I am trying to import from the component scss file like this

```
import styles from "./styles.scss";
```

I get returned an empty object.

This is my webpack config for scss

```
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "style-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  sourceMap: true,
                }
              },
              {
                loader: "resolve-url-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true
                }
              },
              {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

If I try to go got **css-loaded** and set **modules: true** then I will get to content of the file in **styles** but wherever I am using global stylesheet it will break and I will no longer have the classes in the elements.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try to import them like this

```
import "./styles.scss";
```

Comment: annoying, but works